# Accessing external VPN server using raspberry pi

Tags: server, raspberry-pi, client, vpn, openvpn

I need to access university VPN server using raspberry pi. I have provided with the client configuration file of university's VPN. I have surfed over the internet to access a VPN but failed. I have seen alot of examples in which by using openvpn on raspberry pi can easily turns it into a VPN server but what I want to do is to access a VPN which is not present in the same netwok and as far as I know, I being raspberry pi owner is a client. 
Any suggestions regarding this? 
Code below is my configuration file

```
n:version:4
s:network-host:vpngw.fh-kempten.de
n:network-ike-port:500
s:client-auto-mode:pull
s:client-iface:virtual
n:network-mtu-size:1380
n:client-addr-auto:1
s:network-natt-mode:enable
n:network-natt-port:4500
n:network-natt-rate:15
s:network-frag-mode:enable
n:network-frag-size:540
n:network-dpd-enable:1
n:network-notify-enable:0
n:client-banner-enable:1
n:client-dns-used:1
n:client-dns-auto:1
n:client-dns-suffix-auto:1
s:auth-method:mutual-psk-xauth
s:ident-client-type:fqdn
s:ident-client-data:.vpnserver.rz.fh-kempten.de
s:ident-server-type:address
b:auth-mutual-psk:cmVjaGVuemVudHJ1bQ==
s:phase1-exchange:aggressive
n:phase1-dhgroup:2
s:phase1-cipher:3des
n:phase1-keylen:0
s:phase1-hash:md5
n:phase1-life-secs:28800
n:phase1-life-kbytes:0
n:vendor-chkpt-enable:0
s:phase2-transform:esp-3des
n:phase2-keylen:0
s:phase2-hmac:md5
n:phase2-pfsgroup:0
n:phase2-life-secs:28800
n:phase2-life-kbytes:0
s:ipcomp-transform:disabled
s:policy-level:auto
n:policy-nailed:0
n:policy-list-auto:1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not make sense to connect to VPN on same network.
If you need to connect to remote VPN server, you need to install VPN client on your Raspberry Pi (For example OpenVPN).
On their webpage is step-by-step manual, how to install and configure VPN client.
https://openvpn.net/community-resources/how-to/

Comment: I rephrased my query. I will try to follow the instrustions provided on openvpn and will come back again.
Thanks for your recmmendation @koxo